# Get value from json data from array inside another array using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to get a specific value from a specific json object in every array inside another array. The json looks like this (simplified to address the problem):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "previews": [
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "previews": [
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "previews": [
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                },
                {
                    "href": "<URL>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This works for each object:

```
['data'][0]['previews'][3]['href']
['data'][1]['previews'][3]['href']
['data'][2]['previews'][3]['href']
```

What I want to acheive is equivalent to this:

```
['data'][0:2]['previews'][3]['href']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `href` from many objects as a `list`, you may use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as follows:

```py
d = {}  # JSON from the question

def get_third_preview_href(obj):
    return obj['previews'][3]['href']

result = [get_third_preview_href(obj) for obj in d['data']]
```

Or more brave:

```py
result = [obj['previews'][3]['href'] for obj in d['data']]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Tahnk you!